# What is the best way to create own token in substrate?

Tags: token

I want to launch my own token with Substrate chain. What is the best way to implement it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options to launch your own token on Substrate:

- Using the Contract pallet to implement a token, take a look at this [ERC20 token tutorial](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/build-a-token-contract/)
- With the [balances pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/balances)
- Using the EVM pallet to implement a Solidity ERC20 token
- Use the [Assets pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/assets).
- Create your [own pallet](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/work-with-pallets/use-macros-in-a-custom-pallet/).

Take a look into this great [Substrate Seminar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qkqEfToH8w), for more information.

Answer (score 5):

The pallet-balance that comes preconfigured with https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template is the way to go.